# SQL: Display associated value based on Min and Max values

Tags: sql, ms-access, max, min, having

I have tblDump which has ~52,000 records. It is a list of IDs with corresponding dosing times. The relevant variables are `SubjectNumber`, `RECDATE`, `RECTIME`, `FoodType`. Each patient doses twice a day, so there is a `Min(RECTIME)` and `Max(RECTIME)` per `RECDATE`. To display this, I have this so far:

```
 SELECT tblDump.SubjectNumber, tblDump.RECDATE, 
        Min(RECTIME) As MornDose, Max(RECTIME) As EveDose
 FROM tblDump
 GROUP BY tblDump.SubjectNumber, tblDump.RECDATE
 ORDER BY tblDump.SubjectNumber, tblDump.RECDATE Asc;
```

For the variable `FoodType`, there are three possibilities: 1, 2 or 3. I need to print the Subjects whose `Min(RECTIME)` is associated with a 1 and `Max(RECTIME)` is associated with a 3, per day.

I was attempting to make the `HAVING` statement such that the `Foodtype = 1` for `Min(RecTIME)` and `Foodtype = 3` for `Max(RECTIME)`, but I can't get the linguistics correct.

Resolved:

Okay, I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do this but this works. Hopefully this will help someone or someone can post a more efficient method. I used 3 queries, one for the Min Dose time, one for the Max dose time, and one to join them together.

qryMin:

```
SELECT a.SubjectNumber, a.RECDATE, First(a.colm AS MornDose), First(m.FoodType)
FROM (SELECT SubjectNumber, RECDATE, MIN(RECTIME) as colm 
      FROM tblDump GROUP BY SubjectNumber, RECDATE)  AS a 
INNER JOIN tblDump AS m 
        ON (a.colm=m.RECTIME) 
           AND (a.RECDATE = m.RECDATE) 
           AND (a.SubjectNumber = m.SubjectNumber)
GROUP BY a.SubjectNumber, a.RECDATE
ORDER BY a.SubjectNumber, a.RECDATE;
```

qryMax:

```
SELECT a.SubjectNumber, a.RECDATE, First(a.colm) AS MornDose, First(m.FoodType)
FROM (SELECT SubjectNumber, RECDATE, MAX(RECTIME) AS colm 
      FROM tblDump GROUP BY SubjectNumber, RECDATE)  AS a 
INNER JOIN tblDump AS m 
        ON (a.SubjectNumber = m.SubjectNumber) 
           AND (a.RECDATE = m.RECDATE) 
           AND (a.colm = m.RECTIME)
GROUP BY a.SubjectNumber, a.RECDATE
ORDER BY a.SubjectNumber, a.RECDATE;
```

qryCombo:

```
SELECT qryMin.*, qryMax.*
FROM qryMin
INNER JOIN qryMax 
        ON qryMin.SubjectNumber = qryMax.SubjectNumber
WHERE qryMin.RECDATE = qryMax.RECDATE 
      AND qryMin.FoodType = 1 
      AND qryMax.FoodType = 3;
```

Comment: It's perfectly permissable to answer your own question, you know.  And yes, this can be done in one query (if nothing else, by replacing those references to `qryMin` and `qryMax` with those statements, although there are additional shortcuts available).  Also, `RECDATE` and `RECTIME` should really be combined in one timestamp type, which is what you're dealing with.  Although, this does make some of the analysis easier (given you're aggregating by day)....

Comment: Also, what RDBMS (and major version) do you have - there may be a better way to solve this.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I'm actually using access 2010. replacing the references to the queries with the statements, access is requesting that I use the "EXISTS" command which I am not familiar with